# SwiftUI ScrollView doesn't compute custom StaggeredGrid height

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list, swiftui-view

I am trying to create a new grid structure in SwiftUI to show cards with variable heights. To that extent, I use several `LazyVStack`s in a `HStack` and have a condition to display my data items in the correct order. This view works alone, adapts the number of columns to the size of the screen, but when using it in a `ScrollView`, its size is not computed properly and the following views end up beneath the grid instead of below it. Here is the code I used for the grid :

```
struct StaggeredGrid<Element, Content>: View where Content: View {

    var preferredItemWidth: CGFloat
    var data: [Element] = []

    var content: (Element) -> Content

    init(preferredItemWidth: CGFloat, data: [Element], @ViewBuilder content: @escaping (Element) -> Content) {
        self.preferredItemWidth = preferredItemWidth
        self.data = data
        self.content = content
    }

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            HStack(alignment: .top, spacing: 20) {
                ForEach(1...Int(geometry.size.width / preferredItemWidth), id: \.self) { number in
                    LazyVStack(spacing: 20) {
                        ForEach(0..<data.count, id: \.self) { index in
                            if (index+1) % Int(geometry.size.width / preferredItemWidth) == number % Int(geometry.size.width / preferredItemWidth) {
                                content(data[index])
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .padding([.horizontal])
        }
    }
}
```

And the preview to show the behavior :

```
struct StaggeredGrid_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack {
                StaggeredGrid(preferredItemWidth: 160, data: (1...10).map{"Item \($0)"}) { item in
                    Text(item)
                        .foregroundColor(.blue)
                }
                Text("I should be below the grid")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a picture of the preview:
[Wrong appearance in a ScrollView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kYLyC.png)

And a picture when the `ScrollView` is commented out:
[Expected behavior, ScrollView removed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L9PTS.png)

Thank you in advance for any help or clue about this behavior I do not understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I quote [@Asperi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12299030/asperi) :
"ScrollView has no own size and GeometryReader has no own size, so you've got into chicken-egg problem, ie. no-one knows size to render, so collapsed. You must have definite frame size for items inside ScrollView."

Here you have to set the height of your `StaggeredGrid`, or the `GeometryReader` it contains.
In your case its height depends of course on the height of its content (i.e. the HStack). You can read this height (the height of its background / overlay for example) with a Reader. And use it to definite the frame size of your GeometryReader

For example :

```
struct StaggeredGrid<Element, Content>: View where Content: View {

    var preferredItemWidth: CGFloat
    var data: [Element] = []

    var content: (Element) -> Content

    init(preferredItemWidth: CGFloat, data: [Element], @ViewBuilder content: @escaping (Element) -> Content) {
        self.preferredItemWidth = preferredItemWidth
        self.data = data
        self.content = content
    }
    
    @State private var gridHeight: CGFloat = 100

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            HStack(alignment: .top, spacing: 20) {
                ForEach(1...Int(geometry.size.width / preferredItemWidth), id: \.self) { number in
                    LazyVStack(spacing: 20) {
                        ForEach(0..<data.count, id: \.self) { index in
                            if (index+1) % Int(geometry.size.width / preferredItemWidth) == number % Int(geometry.size.width / preferredItemWidth) {
                                content(data[index])
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .overlay(GeometryReader { proxy in
                Color.clear.preference(
                    key: HeightPreferenceKey.self,
                    value: proxy.size.height
                )
            })
            .onPreferenceChange(HeightPreferenceKey.self) {
                gridHeight = $0
            }
            .padding([.horizontal])
        }
        .frame(height: gridHeight)
    }
}

private struct HeightPreferenceKey: PreferenceKey {
    static let defaultValue: CGFloat = 0

    static func reduce(value: inout CGFloat,
                       nextValue: () -> CGFloat) {
        value = nextValue()
    }
}
```

Comment: The use of PreferenceKey fixed my grid, thank you so much !